# pycrypto RC2 encrypt() does not get the right cypher

Tags: python, pycrypto

I have written a simple function to encrypt a message with  [RC2](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/RC2) in Python. The package used is [pycrypto](https://www.dlitz.net/software/pycrypto/api/current/Crypto.Cipher.ARC2-module.html); However the result is not correct, the code as following shown

```
def encrypt_rc2(plain, key):
    b_size = ARC2.block_size

    # PKCS7 padding
    padding_length = b_size - len(plain) % b_size
    c_fill = chr(padding_length)

    plain += c_fill * padding_length
    iv = '\x00' * 8
    alg = ARC2.new(key, ARC2.MODE_CBC, iv)
    return alg.encrypt(plain)
```

The mode used is CBC, the IV is set to all zero and the padding used is PKCS7

In my test, the input plain is **51349910000011**, and the key used is **\x81\xda\x6c\x63\xf2**.

The output (cypher) as following shown (print the integer ordinal)

```
[96, 106, 49, 42, 52, 195, 126, 196, 158, 199, 213, 105, 66, 217, 81, 69]
```

The expected cypher should be (using C# System.Security.Cryptography)

```
[195, 73, 163, 32, 206, 3, 56, 179, 140, 106, 47, 173, 99, 192, 180, 15]
```

Anybody know what's wrong with the code?

Comment: There is a lot of information missing. What are the inputs, outputs and expected outputs? Why are you expecting those outputs?

Comment: @ArtjomB. add input & ouput as you said

Comment: Your code looks fine. Maybe the problem is with the C# code. I don't know of any incompatibility, but maybe there is some difference in the key handling. Good thing that both pycrypto and System.Security.Cryptography are open source, so you can look into the source code yourself.